# Ansible playbook error for Extreme VSP switches running 6.1.3

Tags: networking, ansible

I am brand new to Ansible and Red Hat. I am trying to start very small and just run a basic command on my Avaya / Extreme VSP 8200.

I can successfully run
`ansible switch1 -m cli_command -a "command='show ip route static'" -u testuser -k -e ansible_network_os=voss`
That gives me the output I would expect!

When I execute my playbook, I get an error `fatal: [switch1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Connection type ssh is not valid for this module"}`

I can see on the switch that the SSH session is established, but can't go any further with a playbook.

My hosts playbook looks like

```
- hosts: switch1
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    -
      cli_command:
        command: 'show ip route static'
      name: "Retrieve VSP sys-info"
```

Here is my hosts file:

```
[switch1]
10.10.9.7

[switch1:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
ansible_network_os=voss
ansible_connection=network_cli
```

I am running Ansible version 2.8.2 on Red Hat 4.8.5-39.
I've spent almost 2 days trying to figure out what I'm missing, so any help would be so greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Jonathan

Comment: did you tried "voss_command:" instead of "cli_command" in your playbook task?? ,if not, have a look here for some examples.. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/voss_command_module.html

Comment: I did not, since I was able to get cli_command to work I was satisfied with that. Obviously I'm doing something wrong in my playbook since I can run the ad-hoc command with no issues.